# Novice trying to learn sql....Msg 8114, Level 16, State 5, Line 1 Error converting data type varchar to numeric

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am just beginning to learn DB. I am working on a table and I am receiving error message as follows:

> Msg 8114, Level 16, State 5, Line 1
>   Error converting data type varchar to numeric.

I am inserting data from the following table:

`EMPLOYEE_PAY_TBL`:

```
EMP_ID       POSITION        DATE_HIRE   PAY_RATE   DATE_LAST   SALARY  BONUS
311549902    MARKETING       23-MAY-89              01-MAY-99   4000
442346889    TEAM LEADER     17-JUN-90      14.75   01-JUN-99
```

The table I created is as follows:

```
Emp_id  varchar (20)    not null
position    varchar (25)    not null
date_hire   date        not null
pay_rate    decimal  (4,2)  null
date_last raise date        null
Salary      int     null
Bonus       int     null
```

I cannot figure out why I'm getting the error message or how to correct.

Please help.

Comment: A few suggestions to help you get an answer... 1. Please let us know the specific SQL technology you're using (MYSQL, MSSQL, MariaDB, PostgreSQL, etc). You also might want to use more specific tags with this information. 2. Rather than describing your table structure, please post a CREATE TABLE query that we can run to recreate it - that will allow us to test your problem easier. 3. Please post your INSERT query which you're using to try and insert data into this table.

Comment: can you post your sql statement? also, are you inserting "from" or inserting "into" the table you have specified above?

Comment: Please format your code so it's clearer.

Comment: Thank you for all the comments.  I am using Microsoft SQL Server.

Comment: my code is:   INSERT INTO EMPLOYEE_PAY_TBL
VALUES ('311549902', 'MARKETING', '19890523', '', '19990501', '4000', '')

Comment: Straight off the bat would suggest specifying the columns you are inputting to, so: INSERT INTO EMPLOYEE_PAY_TBL (empid, position, date_hire, pay_rate, date_last_raise_date, salary, bonus)  VALUES ('311549902', 'MARKETING', '19890523', '', '19990501', '4000', '')  From that I can see your bonus column is an int and you are giving it a blank string, try making that a zero and see how you go

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to insert the numeric columns as strings. Especially your columns which will take null values.

In your insert statement you do the  following:

`INSERT INTO EMPLOYEE_PAY_TBL VALUES ('311549902', 'MARKETING', '19890523', '', '19990501', '4000', '')`

You are trying to set the columns pay rate and bonus equal to a empty string which you have in the statement as `''`. An empty string is not a NULL value. It is just a string of zero elements.

So try:

`INSERT INTO EMPLOYEE_PAY_TBL VALUES (311549902, 'MARKETING', '19890523', NULL, '19990501', 4000, NULL)`

A word of caution you are also treating your dates as strings which will eventually give you headaches. As you are new to SQL I will let you cross that bridge when you get there.

Comment: It is absolutely fine for a date formatted in un-separated ISO8601 format yyyyMMdd, which is language neutral. see https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms180878(v=sql.105).aspx#StringLiteralDateandTimeFormats

Comment: @Eric I did not say it was incorrect just that it causes headaches especially when working with international databases where you are guaranteed to have dates that don't fit that format. The problem arises when your server is in a different format than your client. Just a watch out more than a this is not right.